Postgresql create extension works on cluster stored on external drive, but not on main cluster
I built Rdkit on Windows with the Postgresql Cartridge. I stored a database on an external drive on a cluster with a different port than the cluster on my main hard drive (created with initdb -D D:/data and started with pg_ctl -D D:/data start).
I can see rdkit extension on both clusters when calling
select * from pg_available_extensions where name ilike '%rdkit%';

I get (generally) the following
 name  | default_version | installed_version |                    comment
-------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 rdkit | 4.6.0           |                   | Cheminformatics functionality for PostgreSQL.

On the external cluster, I was able to call CREATE EXTENSION rdkit; successfully in a new database and I get the following for that specific database
 name  | default_version | installed_version |                    comment
-------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------
 rdkit | 4.6.0           | 4.6.0             | Cheminformatics functionality for PostgreSQL.

Now, my issue is that on the main cluster, when I try to create the extension I get the following error:
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib/rdkit.dll": The specified module could not be found.

I checked that folder and the rdkit.dll is there.
If I create a new cluster with  initdb -D path/to/the/data/folder (and change port for this new cluster in postgresql.conf to 5430), I can create the extension without any issue on a new database.
I don't know if it is specific to rdkit or if the issue is related to something else.
Edit
It seems that the issue is only with the original cluster located in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data (so at the same place where PostgreSQL is installed) and created when I installed PostgreSQL through the EDB installer. Is it possible that the rdkit extension works only on clusters that were created after rdkit is installed?
